# Why Last Id generate with percentage sign and 20 no with it

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

it is my code
i want to insert the last id in another page . i have created the function and pass the last id using ajax .but when it redirected or clicking on submit button it generate the last id %20 with actual last id  like %2021

```
public function create_action()
{

        $rand=rand(0000,9999);
        $data=array(
            'name'=>$_POST['name'],
            'mr'=>$_POST['mr'],
            'gender'=>$_POST['gender'],
            'email'=>$_POST['email'],
            'mobile_code'=>$_POST['mobile_code'],
            'mobile_no'=>$_POST['mobile_no'],
            'password'=>$_POST['password'],
            'confirm_password'=>$_POST['confirm_password'],
            'terms'=>$_POST['terms'],
            'otp'=>$rand,
            'created'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->Crud_model->SaveData('registration',$data);
        $last_id=$this->db->insert_id();

    
        if(!empty($last_id))
        {
            $lastid=$last_id;
        }
        else{
            $lastid=0;
        }
        echo json_encode($lastid);
        
}
```

and it is my ajax code

```
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
      //  cache:false,
      contentType: false,   
       processData:false,
       datatype:'json',
        url:'<?php echo site_url('Welcome/create_action')?>',
        data:form_data,
        success:function(data)
        {
         // alert(returndata);
         // var obj=$.parseJSON(returndata);
         // console.log(obj);
          if(data)
          {
            console.log(data);
            window.location.href="<?php echo site_url()?>" + "/Welcome/registration_page/"+data;

          }
        }
      });

     }
```

everything is fine but last id generate with like
%2042

it taking the space and giving the such output. i have tried all the thing but nothing worked please suggest.

Comment: I would bet var_dump'ing out `$lastid` would not show the space, you might want to look at your template or at top of file etc for  whitespace ` <?php`

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i code it it work and everything was right . but after two days showing like this.

Comment: your function and your ajax request not have error

Comment: i recommend to you that trace one by one line of your code will you find your mistake good luke